# Redirect *example.com/* to https://example.com/*

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

I have an SSL certificate without "www" in front of my URL and I'm experiencing issues with Javascript's same-origin policy when users switch from http to https.

I would like to know how (what to type in .htaccess?) to redirect everything (`http://www.example.com, http://example.com, and https://www.example.com`) to `https://example.com`.

Also, I'd like for anything typed in after my URL (`*example.com/*`)
to also redirect with https before the typed URL. (`https://example.com/[whatever was typed]`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Excellent! The code that you gave me accomplished exactly what I needed. To note for others, I had additional .htacesss files in separate locations (DOCUMENT_ROOT/example directory) which I needed to delete because they were overriding your code.